# Python: ¿Cómo crear un atajo personalizado en un Entry?

Tags: python, tkinter

Estuve buscando, pero no encontré forma de hacerlo y no estoy seguro si es posible. Mi objetivo es que mientras se escribe en un **Entry** (correspondiente a la libreria Tkinter), se pueda agregar un carácter (que no se encuentra en el código ascii) con una **combinación de teclas personalizada**s, es decir, **simulando el funcionamiento del código ascii**.
No tengo código para mostrar, pero por ejemplo, que mediante una combinación de teclas pueda introducir:

```
λ,∩,∪
```

.
¿Es posible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Si es posible hacerlo. Aqui te dejo un código que hace eso mismo:

```
from tkinter import *

Tk()

e=Entry()
e.pack()

def char(Event):
    # OBTENGO EL ENTRY #
    entry = Event.widget

    # UBICO EL CARACTER EN DONDE ESTÁ EL CURSOR #
    entry.insert(entry.index("insert"), "∩")

    # SI YA EXISTIA LA COMBINACION DE TECLAS, EVITO QUE SE CREE EL CARACTER ORIGINAL #
    return "break"


# HAGO QUE AL PRESIONAR ALT+9+4 SE LLAME A LA FUNCIÓN CHAR #
e.bind("<Alt_L>94", char)
```

Para bindear combinaciones de 3 o más teclas la respuesta a esta pregunta te puede servir, es lo que yo usé: [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56204344/binding-multiple-keys-to-a-function-in-tkinter-python#:~:text=In%20tkinter%20you%20can%20put,and%20it%20will%20run%20function.&text=By%20just%20adding%20the%20and,the%20tab%20and%20enter%20keys](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56204344/binding-multiple-keys-to-a-function-in-tkinter-python#:%7E:text=In%20tkinter%20you%20can%20put,and%20it%20will%20run%20function.&text=By%20just%20adding%20the%20and,the%20tab%20and%20enter%20keys).